# display the value of the json response returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this json codes that I use to send post and pull data (refer below)

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/employee-attendance-history' ,
        data: { id : $(this).attr("data-id") },
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            if(response.success){
               console.log(JSON.stringify(response.emp_logs));
                $.each(response.emp_logs, function(index, value){
                    alert(value.actual_time);

                });
            }
        }
    });
```

I have this json response

```
[{"work_date":"2015-06-13","day":"SAT","log_type":"-","actual_time":"-","late_in":"-","under_time":"-","break_time":"-","remarks":"Holiday","class":"holiday-red"},{"work_date":"2015-06-14","day":"SUN","log_type":"-","actual_time":"-","late_in":"-","under_time":"-","break_time":"-","remarks":"Holiday","class":"holiday-red"},{"work_date":"2015-06-15","day":"MON","log_type":"-","actual_time":"-","late_in":"-","under_time":"-","break_time":"-","remarks":"No Record","class":"data_holder"},{"work_date":"2015-06-16","day":"TUE","log_type":"-","actual_time":"-","late_in":"-","under_time":"-","break_time":"-","remarks":"No Record","class":"data_holder"},{"work_date":"2015-06-17","day":"WED","log_type":"LOGGED","actual_time":{"no":376,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvDYw7O/hfZFqD8e3s2YB2KW","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-06-17","log_type":"LOGGED","time_in_start":"17:34:58","time_out_end":"17:35:26","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"0","reason":"","update_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-06-17","day":"WED","log_type":"LOGGED","actual_time":{"no":377,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvDYw7O/hfZFqD8e3s2YB2KW","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-06-17","log_type":"LOGGED","time_in_start":"17:35:46","time_out_end":"17:49:39","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"0","reason":"","update_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-06-17","day":"WED","log_type":"OB","actual_time":{"no":378,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvDYw7O/hfZFqD8e3s2YB2KW","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-06-17","log_type":"OB","time_in_start":"17:36:21","time_out_end":"17:36:39","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"0","reason":"","update_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-06-17","day":"WED","log_type":"BREAK","actual_time":{"no":379,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvDYw7O/hfZFqD8e3s2YB2KW","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-06-17","log_type":"BREAK","time_in_start":"17:36:59","time_out_end":"17:37:31","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"0","reason":"","update_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-06-18","day":"THU","log_type":"LOGGED","actual_time":{"no":380,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvDavWR5Zk1I8j8e3s2YB2KW","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-06-18","log_type":"LOGGED","time_in_start":"07:07:13","time_out_end":"17:06:49","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"0","reason":"","update_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-06-18","day":"THU","log_type":"OB","actual_time":{"no":381,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvDavWR5Zk1I8j8e3s2YB2KW","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-06-18","log_type":"OB","time_in_start":"10:30:36","time_out_end":"16:04:22","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"0","reason":"","update_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-06-19","day":"FRI","log_type":"LOGGED","actual_time":{"no":382,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvCbhW1R+oh7Qj8e3s2YB2KW","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-06-19","log_type":"LOGGED","time_in_start":"07:09:45","time_out_end":"17:20:13","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"0","reason":"","update_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-06-19","day":"FRI","log_type":"BREAK","actual_time":{"no":383,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvCbhW1R+oh7Qj8e3s2YB2KW","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-06-19","log_type":"BREAK","time_in_start":"12:22:36","time_out_end":"12:52:01","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"0","reason":"","update_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-06-20","day":"SAT","log_type":"-","actual_time":"-","late_in":"-","under_time":"-","break_time":"-","remarks":"Holiday","class":"holiday-red"},{"work_date":"2015-06-21","day":"SUN","log_type":"-","actual_time":"-","late_in":"-","under_time":"-","break_time":"-","remarks":"Holiday","class":"holiday-red"},{"work_date":"2015-06-22","day":"MON","log_type":"LOGGED","actual_time":{"no":581,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvCoJJ+G2T/eLTVwZZqo/02y","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-06-22","log_type":"LOGGED","time_in_start":"06:43:50","time_out_end":"00:00:00","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-06-22 16:18:04"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-06-22","day":"MON","log_type":"OB","actual_time":{"no":593,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvCoJJ+G2T/eLRbzrKkHGmVk","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-06-22","log_type":"OB","time_in_start":"09:32:46","time_out_end":"13:39:27","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-06-22 21:39:27"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-06-23","day":"TUE","log_type":"LOGGED","actual_time":{"no":618,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvCoJJ+G2T/eLWFsiTsTiZ+V","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-06-23","log_type":"LOGGED","time_in_start":"07:22:41","time_out_end":"17:25:36","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-06-24 01:25:36"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-06-23","day":"TUE","log_type":"OB","actual_time":{"no":639,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvCoJJ+G2T/eLTAqd2ST+e8L","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-06-23","log_type":"OB","time_in_start":"08:50:08","time_out_end":"16:39:52","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-06-24 00:39:52"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-06-24","day":"WED","log_type":"LOGGED","actual_time":{"no":661,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvCoJJ+G2T/eLZWs1yoUNpze","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-06-24","log_type":"LOGGED","time_in_start":"07:23:52","time_out_end":"17:27:54","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-06-25 01:27:54"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-06-24","day":"WED","log_type":"OB","actual_time":{"no":667,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvCoJJ+G2T/eLThGIcaWCaE2","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-06-24","log_type":"OB","time_in_start":"07:47:53","time_out_end":"16:04:08","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-06-25 00:04:08"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-06-25","day":"THU","log_type":"LOGGED","actual_time":{"no":691,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvCoJJ+G2T/eLUgbfzmWxck8","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-06-25","log_type":"LOGGED","time_in_start":"07:05:55","time_out_end":"17:07:52","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-06-26 01:07:52"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-06-25","day":"THU","log_type":"OB","actual_time":{"no":699,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvCoJJ+G2T/eLd2FV+XA/dDJ","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-06-25","log_type":"OB","time_in_start":"07:40:46","time_out_end":"15:48:58","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-06-25 23:48:58"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-06-26","day":"FRI","log_type":"LOGGED","actual_time":{"no":726,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvCoJJ+G2T/eLSgXBmspqt0V","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-06-26","log_type":"LOGGED","time_in_start":"07:09:20","time_out_end":"17:06:01","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-06-27 01:06:01"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-06-26","day":"FRI","log_type":"OB","actual_time":{"no":745,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvCoJJ+G2T/eLQCNUXf4vubw","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-06-26","log_type":"OB","time_in_start":"09:21:17","time_out_end":"12:17:12","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-06-26 20:17:12"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-06-27","day":"SAT","log_type":"-","actual_time":"-","late_in":"-","under_time":"-","break_time":"-","remarks":"Holiday","class":"holiday-red"},{"work_date":"2015-06-28","day":"SUN","log_type":"-","actual_time":"-","late_in":"-","under_time":"-","break_time":"-","remarks":"Holiday","class":"holiday-red"},{"work_date":"2015-06-29","day":"MON","log_type":"LOGGED","actual_time":{"no":763,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvCoJJ+G2T/eLQzlkv8uQX7X","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-06-29","log_type":"LOGGED","time_in_start":"07:08:57","time_out_end":"17:51:47","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-06-30 01:51:47"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-06-29","day":"MON","log_type":"OB","actual_time":{"no":784,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvCoJJ+G2T/eLYkdYV/b0zYa","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-06-29","log_type":"OB","time_in_start":"10:46:51","time_out_end":"17:27:38","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-06-30 01:27:38"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-06-30","day":"TUE","log_type":"LOGGED","actual_time":{"no":797,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvCoJJ+G2T/eLUN1IoHU5h1B","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-06-30","log_type":"LOGGED","time_in_start":"07:06:33","time_out_end":"17:07:15","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-07-01 01:07:15"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-06-30","day":"TUE","log_type":"OB","actual_time":{"no":817,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvCoJJ+G2T/eLTNQCI7tJkZy","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-06-30","log_type":"OB","time_in_start":"08:41:44","time_out_end":"16:15:23","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-07-01 00:15:23"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-07-01","day":"WED","log_type":"-","actual_time":"-","late_in":"-","under_time":"-","break_time":"-","remarks":"No Record","class":"data_holder"},{"work_date":"2015-07-02","day":"THU","log_type":"LOGGED","actual_time":{"no":850,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvDGIpOW8+dD6Ze2PyBJhwyg","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-07-02","log_type":"LOGGED","time_in_start":"06:59:53","time_out_end":"17:02:39","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-07-03 01:02:39"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-07-02","day":"THU","log_type":"OB","actual_time":{"no":865,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvDGIpOW8+dD6bqypWUZSfLs","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-07-02","log_type":"OB","time_in_start":"08:17:27","time_out_end":"15:41:30","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-07-02 23:41:30"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-07-03","day":"FRI","log_type":"LOGGED","actual_time":{"no":887,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvDGIpOW8+dD6csElvUHp6JO","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-07-03","log_type":"LOGGED","time_in_start":"07:33:55","time_out_end":"18:11:32","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-07-04 02:11:32"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-07-03","day":"FRI","log_type":"BREAK","actual_time":{"no":904,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvDGIpOW8+dD6cPh9VFegX5w","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-07-03","log_type":"BREAK","time_in_start":"12:19:11","time_out_end":"12:57:34","late_in":0,"break_time":38,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-07-03 20:57:34"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":38},{"work_date":"2015-07-04","day":"SAT","log_type":"-","actual_time":"-","late_in":"-","under_time":"-","break_time":"-","remarks":"Holiday","class":"holiday-red"},{"work_date":"2015-07-05","day":"SUN","log_type":"-","actual_time":"-","late_in":"-","under_time":"-","break_time":"-","remarks":"Holiday","class":"holiday-red"},{"work_date":"2015-07-06","day":"MON","log_type":"LOGGED","actual_time":{"no":932,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvDGIpOW8+dD6Wk8PaVnw2av","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-07-06","log_type":"LOGGED","time_in_start":"07:25:10","time_out_end":"17:50:06","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-07-07 01:50:06"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-07-06","day":"MON","log_type":"OB","actual_time":{"no":944,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvDGIpOW8+dD6bABE86EadnD","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-07-06","log_type":"OB","time_in_start":"08:53:03","time_out_end":"16:49:37","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-07-07 00:49:37"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-07-07","day":"TUE","log_type":"LOGGED","actual_time":{"no":964,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvDGIpOW8+dD6dmTXoC/E08T","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-07-07","log_type":"LOGGED","time_in_start":"07:16:50","time_out_end":"18:53:31","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-07-08 02:53:31"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-07-07","day":"TUE","log_type":"OB","actual_time":{"no":990,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvDGIpOW8+dD6ZxJDNyDQ2g/","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-07-07","log_type":"OB","time_in_start":"09:17:22","time_out_end":"16:35:18","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-07-08 00:35:18"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-07-08","day":"WED","log_type":"LOGGED","actual_time":{"no":1008,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvDGIpOW8+dD6RU6K4P5Sui+","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-07-08","log_type":"LOGGED","time_in_start":"07:02:13","time_out_end":"17:46:22","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-07-09 01:46:22"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0},{"work_date":"2015-07-08","day":"WED","log_type":"OB","actual_time":{"no":1019,"keylog":"7DMhrL8dvvDGIpOW8+dD6a2NAXsWd2/e","employee_id":"MMMFLB032","log_date":"2015-07-08","log_type":"OB","time_in_start":"07:34:48","time_out_end":"12:28:36","late_in":0,"break_time":0,"under_time":0,"override_user":"","reason":"","update_date":"2015-07-08 20:28:36"},"remarks":"-","late_in":0,"under_time":0,"break_time":0}]
```

I looped through that json response and tried to alert the "actual_time" value (value.actual_time) but some returns me "undefined", some returns me "-" and some returns me a time stamp, any ideas why it returns undefined?

Comment: What's the value of actual_time in the database?

Comment: I have no access for the back end that this codes was in associate with, sorry. As you can see in the json response, there are actual_time object that is not an object arrays (no objects nested within) and some are just flat objects so it returns me undefined and some returns me a value.

Comment: In the JSON you posted, most of the `actual_time` properties refer to an Object, and not the String `"-"`. You cannot directly `alert()` an Object. Stringify it first, or use `console.log()` instead of alert, it's much more convenient. https://jsfiddle.net/h2npazh5/

Comment: This is a HTTP POST. Are you submitting the correct data to the URL in order to get the expected response?

Comment: @blex : good point, but you can see the whole json response so the problem is not with alert.

Comment: @JavaScript: its the json array of object from one of the array object response that has been fetch back.

Comment: thank you guys for the help, i find this complicated and hard so i tried different approach and its all good now :) CHEERS!